# background-image drawn on different areas in body and h1

Tags: html, css

Why does the drawable area of the `body` element include the margin? Can it be changed?

Here is an [example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic) (you can use your favorite editor as well):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background: url('http://www.w3schools.com/css/paper.gif') no-repeat;
    border: 10px dashed red;
    padding: 50px;
    margin: 25px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-origin: content-box;
}

h1 {
    background: url('http://www.w3schools.com/css/paper.gif') no-repeat;
    border: 10px dashed red;
    padding: 50px;
    background-attachment: scroll;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

If you compare the two elements, the `background-image` for a `h1` element does not fill the margin area, where it does so for the `body` element. If I missed this in the CSS specifications, could you help me find a reference?

I tried to use `background-origin: content-box` for `body` to change this behavior, but that did not work.

Also, if I remove the `background-repeat` property of the `h1` element, then its `background-image` extends into its border as well, why does this happen?

Comment: could you explain more? I'm also a little confuse on your question.

Comment: I took the liberty of changing the question a little, I hope I understood the author's question correctly.

Comment: ok, guys. Go to tryit online editor, paste my code there, you can see, that background image of h1 sits inside red border, but background image of body isn't, however they both have same css settings. Moreover, background of body sits inside margin! So I'm trying to  understand why is that so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution in some Russian's top secret nuclear rocket basement: you should set css margin to HTML tag, then everything, include body's background image will move:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background: url('http://www.w3schools.com/css/paper.gif') no-repeat;
    border: 10px dashed red;
    padding: 50px;
    margin: 25px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-origin: content-box;
}

h1 {
    background: url('http://www.w3schools.com/css/paper.gif') no-repeat;
    border: 10px dashed red;
    padding: 50px;
    background-attachment: scroll;
}
html{
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The margin in CSS sets the amount of area that you can't render elements in, it's as it describes a margin.

This behavior can be explained by the [box model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp).

So if you set a margin of 25px it means that it won't let you draw anything related to that element with in it.

I think the code you are looking for (I'm assuming) is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    margin: 25px;
}

#content { 
    background:url('http://www.w3schools.com/css/paper.gif');
    border: 10px dashed red;
    padding: 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-origin: padding-box;
}

h1{
    background:url('http://www.w3schools.com/css/paper.gif') no-repeat;
    border: 10px dashed red;
    padding: 50px;
    background-attachment: scroll;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="content">
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

This separates your CSS out of the body, where you don't really have the ability to apply the background-origin.

Comment: Thanks, but I know these king "container" or "wraper" techniques. I'm asking where such behavior is coming from.

Comment: I've updated my answer, but this is due to the box model http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp